# Batch file to shutdown computer through remote desktop in Windows XP

Tags: batch-file, windows-xp, remote-desktop, shutdown

I have a Windows Vista workstation that I use the majority of the time, but I occasionally need to remote desktop into a Windows XP workstation. Because of the differences in resolution, the start menu in my remote desktop session is not visible unless I either full-screen (which I like to avoid so I can still see the start menu and notification tray on my vista workstation) or scroll to the bottom (but I'm lazy!).

I decided to create a **batch file to shutdown the Windows XP machine while using Remote Desktop into it**. It's important that it have a prompt of some kind in case I were to somehow accidentally click it from the desktop.

Here's the batch file source:

```
pause

echo 1
shutdown /s /f
echo 2
```

Yet the file seems to loop at the shutdown command. Here's the output from the batch file:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Kiley\Desktop>pause
Press any key to continue . . .

C:\Documents and Settings\Kiley\Desktop>echo 1
1

C:\Documents and Settings\Kiley\Desktop>shutdown /s /f

C:\Documents and Settings\Kiley\Desktop>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

It seems to loop like this over and over. I've googled the issue in hopes that this is a common problem with a workaround, but I cannot seem to find an explanation. I've tried using the /t switch as well (to specify time), as well as doing an exit command immediately after the shutdown, and it always seems to produce the same behavior as above.

### I also tried creating a similar but different batch file like so...

```
@ECHO OFF

:choice
set /P c=SHUTDOWN[Y/N]?
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :do_shutdown
goto :choice


:somewhere

shutdown -s -f
```

But as soon as I type "y" and press enter, the batch file exits and the machine does not shutdown.

Does anyone have any thoughts, advice, or suggestions? The problem is of little importance, but now I'm just curious...

**EDIT:**
It was suggested that I try using the "-" character to denote a switch instead of "/". This produces the same behavior. However, what's interesting is that I am able to run the following command in a command prompt from the XP workstation to correctly commence shutdown from a command prompt:

```
shutdown -s
```

I tried using the /m switch from my vista workstation, and the command prompt that pops up when double-clicking the batch file exits as soon as the shutdown command is issued. When I try running the shutdown command with the /m switch from the command prompt by itself, I get the following output:

```
C:\Windows\system32>shutdown /s /f /m \\WORKSTATION-V5
WORKSTATION-V5: Access is denied.(5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first code snippet you used / for switches instead of - . Since you are remotely connected to the machine, all you would need to do is specify the code as follows:

```
shutdown -s -f
```

If you are allowed to send remote commands to the computer, instead of using remote desktop to manually access the machine, you can type the following command in YOUR command line and not the remote computer:

```
shutdown -s -f -m \\computername
```

EDIT:

To create a DOS prompt for a shutdown via BATCH SCRIPT:

```
:START
SET /p sd=Would you like to shutdown? [ Y ] or [ N ]     :
IF "%sd%"=="Y" GOTO:SHUTDOWN
IF "%sd%"=="y" GOTO:SHUTDOWN
IF "%sd%"=="n" GOTO:EOF
IF "%sd%"=="N" GOTO:EOF
ECHO Incorrect Answer... Please Try Again
PAUSE
GOTO:START
:SHUTDOWN
shutdown -s
```

Comment: Did you test using - instead of / for the switches? I had tried that earlier and upon your suggested decided to try it again as a sanity check; it produces identical output to the original problem. For the record, the help text when doing "shutdown -?" or "shutdown /?" shows the switches as slashes. I also tried your suggestion of using the -m switch with \\COMPUTERNAME which looked promising... Unfortunately I got an access denied message, but otherwise I think it probably would've worked. Good idea.

Comment: For windows XP its -. Not sure about vista. However, I will edit the post for a shutdown prompt for you.

Comment: Your script worked great! It helped me to realize that I had a typo in the original script that I was using. I made a few tweaks (including @ECHO OFF) and posted the resulting script in my answer. Thanks for the help, you rock!

Answer (score 0):

After trying a few different things, here's the solution that I ended up settling with:

I created a shutdown shortcut on the XP machine by right-clicking on the desktop and entering the following as a new shortcut path:

```
shutdown -s
```

As I mentioned in the question, I wanted a fail-safe in case I were to accidentally start a shutdown. Since the OS gives a 30 second timer after entering the shutdown command via the shortcut above, I decided to create an abort shortcut:

```
shutdown -a
```

### EDIT

**Mechaflash** provided a working solution. After reviewing the difference between his script and my original prompting for Y/N script, I realized that I had a typo in my script: the GOTO on the Y condition pointed to a section that didn't exist! I made some slight modifications to his source so this is what I'm using today:

```
@ECHO OFF
:START
SET /p sd=Would you like to shutdown? [y to continue]     :
IF /I "%sd%"=="y" GOTO:SHUTDOWN
GOTO:EOF

:SHUTDOWN
shutdown -s
```

Comment: I'm a nub... totally forgot about /I switch for IF *blush*